# Ostream & istream as constructor arguements

Tags: c++

I need to use istream and ostream as constructor arguments for my class but im getting a no typename in std error. Can anyone help?? This is ugent.

...

```
#ifndef MENUINTERFACE_H
#define MENUINTERFACE_H
#include <iostream>

namespace core {

class MenuInterface
{
public:
    /**
     * @brief MenuInterface
     * @param display
     * @param input
     */
    MenuInterface(std::cout &display, std::cin &input);

    /**
     * @brief displayWelcome
     * @param author
     * @param title
     */
    void displayWelcome(std::string author, std::string title);

    /**
     * @brief run
     */
    void run();
};

} // core

#endif // MENUINTERFACE_H
```

...

Comment: _"I need to use istream and ostream as constructor arguments for my class"_ Then simply type that thing! You typed something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::cout` and `std::cin` are variable names, not type names.

You need to use `istream` and `ostream`, so use them.

```
MenuInterface(std::ostream &display, std::istream &input);
```

Comment: Wait, no im getting an error saying the constructor is protected.

Comment: @Nozomu I don't get it. My vote goes to MikeCat.

Comment: @Nozomu Are you trying to make a copy of the streams?  You can't do that.

Comment: field of type 'std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') has protected default constructor

Comment: no, passing them in as a reference.

Comment: @Nozomu You'll need to provide a [mcve] then.  Keeping a reference is fine.

Comment: This class is just meant to handle the logic for displaying stuff to the console, and apparently we cant refer to cin and cout directly, it must be done through a reference that is passed into the constructor. Why we have to do it this way I dont know. I certainly wouldn't be doing this if I had a choice.

Comment: "The MenuInterface MUST NOT refer to cin/cout directly: instead references to the input and output streams MUST be passed to the MenuInterface constructor." That's all that the specs say

Comment: Passing them as a reference then trying to assign them to a member that is not a reference?

Comment: no, the error is in the cpp file where the constructor is defined. Haven't tried to assign the arguments to any member variables yet

Comment: Give us a [mcve] and the complete copy/pasted error you're receiving.

Comment: Not sure how much more information i can give you, the specs are very unclear. This class is meant to handle all logic regarding display information to the user. For some reasons they want us to not refer to cin or cout directly, and i must pass the streams into the constructor and to a member variable. When i try and define the constructor, it doesnt allow the arguements due to the error i specified before.

Comment: field of type 'std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') has protected default constructor

Comment: Here is [an example of using reference to `std::cin` and `std::cout`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nfjGLEY5LcAUne6h).

Comment: It is hard to guess why the code you refuse to show us doesn't work. Hopefully the simple example @MikeCAT provided will help you.